# Regex for JAVA to get optional group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I try to match non english text from `用量` to `name=用量` and `用量2` to `name=用量` and `number=2`. I tried `(\p{L}+)(\d*)` on RegexPlanet, it works, but when get it run in java, can not get the `2` out the second test case.

Here's the code:

```
String pt = "(?<name>\\p{L}+)(?<number>\\d*)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pt).matcher(t.trim());
m.find();
System.out.println("Using [" + pt + "] vs [" + t + "] GC=>" + 
m.groupCount());
NameID n = new NameID();
n.name = m.group(1);

if (m.groupCount() > 2) {
    try {
        String ind = m.group(2);
        n.id = Integer.parseInt(ind);
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

Comment: it is \\ in the String constant,

Comment: Your pattern has 2 capturing groups, so `m.groupCount()` will be 2. I don't know why you check that though, because it'll always be exactly 2 with that regex (`pt` value). Anyway, being 2, the `if (m.groupCount() > 2)` will also be false.

Comment: Unrelated, but why did you create *named* capture groups, when you then use them by position, not by name?

Comment: if try it on http://www.regexplanet.com/ , you can see it is getting 3 groups , 0 full text,
1 only chars 
2 will get the number  if it is there , 
not sure why someone vote down my question before understanding ??

Comment: @user5616998 See my update. `groupCount()` does only count *your* groups.

Comment: As I already said, your regex defines 2 groups, so `groupCount()` will be 2. `group(0)` doesn't count, because it's not an actual "capture group", but just the capture of the entire match. The `if` statement is meaningless, because it will **always** be false, and is the reason you don't "see" your number.

Answer (score 2):

```
String t = "用量2";
String pt = "^(?<name>\\p{L}+)(?<number>\\d*)$";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pt).matcher(t.trim());
if (m.matches()) {
    String name = m.group("name");
    Integer id = m.group("number").length() > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(m.group("number")) : null;
    System.out.println("name=" + name + ", id=" + id); // name=用量, id=2
}
```

Your regex works fine, but your Java code has some issues. See javadoc for `groupCount()`:

> Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. It is not included in this count.

Comment: Ha, thanks ,another problem for counting from zero or 1

Comment: @user5616998 You mean, another problem of not reading the javadoc.